# How to lower refresh rate on external display (projector) from 75 hz to 60 hz

Tags: display, external-monitor, display-manager, projector

I have a projector that is 3D Ready, but it can only handle a refresh rate of 60 Hz to use the 3D settings, yet for some reason it defaults to 75 Hz when I plug it in through the HDMI port (the only video out on my laptop) and I cannot figure out how to change it. I have easily been able to use the 3D settings on my Mac so I know it works. I'm not so great at the terminal but I'm not afraid to use it if you can give me clear steps. Of course, it would be great if it could "remember" the refresh rate when I plug it in, but I would settle for having to remind it each time I plug it in.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a setting for the display in the GUI Settings / Display? There *should* be (at least used to be) options to change the refresh there.

Or in a terminal using `xrandr -r 60` should work (might need to use `--output ...` (maybe `--output HDMI-0`?) or `--screen ...` before. Try just `xrandr` to see what it tells you are available modes & info.